# How to use an observable in angular 2 guards' canActivate()

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have created an authentication guard for my angular2 rc5 application.

I am also using a redux store. In that store I keep the user's authentication state.

I read that the guard can return an observable or promise (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards)

I can't seem to find a way for the guard to wait until the store/observable is **updated** and only **after** that update return the guard because the default value of the store will always be false.

First try:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  @select(['user', 'authenticated']) authenticated$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {}

  canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // updated after a while ->
      this.authenticated$.subscribe((auth) => {

        // will only reach here after the first update of the store
        if (auth) { resolve(true); }

        // it will always reject because the default value
        // is always false and it takes time to update the store
        reject(false);

      });

    });

  }

}
```

Second try:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  @select(['user', 'authenticated']) authenticated$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {}

  canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // tried to convert it for single read since canActivate is called every time. So I actually don't want to subscribe here. 
      let auth = this.authenticated$.toPromise(); 

      auth.then((authenticated) => {

        if (authenticated) { resolve(true); }

        reject(false);

      });

      auth.catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18991

Comment: Any of the below answers fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to an observable, you can provide a callback function; in the example below, I call it `CompleteGet`.  `CompleteGet()` will only be invoked on a successful get that returns data and not an error.  You place whatever follow on logic you need in the callback function.

```
getCursenByDateTest(){
 this.cursenService
   .getCursenValueByDateTest("2016-7-30","2016-7-31")
   .subscribe(p => {
     this.cursens = p;
     console.log(p)
     console.log(this.cursens.length);
   },
   error => this.error = error,
   () => this.CompleteGet());
}

completeGet() {
   // the rest of your logic here - only executes on obtaining result.
}
```

I believe you can also add a .do() to the observable subscription to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: In my first example I am using that callback. Problem is that the store will successfully return data. But that is the default value. I want to wait for the first update of the store observable which contains the real authentication value.

Comment: Then I would subscribe to the store observable separately and proceed when it returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is force the observable to update:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authenticated$.take(1);
}
```

Edit:
canActivate waits for the source observable to complete, and (most likely, I don't know what happens behind the scenes), the `authenticated$` observable emits `.next()`, not `.complete()`

From documentation: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-take
`.take(1)` method takes first value emitted by the source observable and then completes

Edit2:
I just looked at snippet you pasted, and I was right - the `store.select()` observable never completes, it always emits `.next`

Comment: Does it wait for the stream to have the wanted update?

Comment: yes, it won't emit anything until the source observable emits
I edited my answer with more explanation

Comment: As I understood, you can't keep tracking the observable, after it emits the first event, the accress permision of the route will be permanent, even if the observable emit a different value later. This is not good for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe doesn't return an Observable.
However, you can use the map operator like that:

```
this.authenticated$.map(
    authenticated => {
        if(authenticated) {
            return true;
        } 
    return false;
    }
 ).first() // or .take(1) to complete on the first event emit
```