# How can I get the single latest value from an infinite RxJs stream that is not the initial value?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, rxjs

#### The concept

This is a mocked angular2 project.

When consuming the observable stream from the redux store I tried to filter first and then take/takeLast/last the latest value. 
After that I want to resolve the promise when the stream completes but it does not when using takeLast operator.

So the question is: **What operator setup can I use to get the latest value from the stream**?

#### The setup

I simplified my Angular 2 setup to this gist of RxJs usage.

- source observable is managed by redux library and is not completed
- service is providing some logic to retrieve the latest value from the stream
- component is consuming value promise style

Here is a working example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/markus_falk/an41z6g9/

The redux store mock:

```
var latestTime$ = new Rx.Subject();
setInterval(function(){
     latestTime$.onNext(Date.now()); 
}, 2000);
```

The service injectable mock:

```
var timeStore = null;
var getLatestTime = function() {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

     latestTime$

     /* 
        filter out 'null' for when the button is clicked
        before the store updates the first time
      */
     .filter(function(x) {
        console.log('filter: ', x);
        return x === typeof('number');
     })

     // try to end to stream by taking the last from the stream ?!?!?!?
     .takeLast(1)

     // handle promise
     .subscribe(

       function (x) {
         console.log('Next: ' + x);
         // store latest stream value
         timeStore = x;
       },
       function (err) {
         console.log('Error: ' + err);
         reject(err)
       },
       function () {
         console.log('Completed');
         // pass on latest value of endless when stream completes 
         resolve(timeStore);
       }

    );

  });

};
```

And a consuming mock component:

```
document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  var time = getLatestTime();

  time.then((latestTime) => {
    console.log('latestTime: ', latestTime);
  });

  time.catch((err) => {
    console.log('oh oh: ', err);
  });

}, false);
```

Comment: I'm not sure really get the gist of the question's code or the fiddle, but an answer to your question's title would be: `latestTime$.skip(1).take(1).toPromise()`. The `takeLast` operator won't emit anything until the underlying observable completes - that appears to the be your problem - and you shouldn't need to create your own promise.

Comment: I think you got the gist. Problem with `skip(1).take(1)` is that it will take the second entry in the stream but I need the last one.

Comment: I think you can use just [`last()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-last) operator or if you want to skip the first value and take the last use `skip(1).last()`.

Comment: Just tried in the fiddle. `skip(1).last()` will not even call next?

Comment: No, because `last()` emits only the last value from Observable after it completes. See http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/last.html

Comment: That explains why I cannot get the value in the complete because `latestTime$` never does. How would you extract the last value then?

Comment: `last()` operator calls next when the source Observable completes. This means that you need to move `resolve(timeStore);` to the "next" callable and the `latestTime$` needs to complete. Since `latestTime$` is a `Subject` you need to call `latestTime$.oncompleted()`. See my answer below with demo.

Answer (score 2):

This should simulate your situation.

See live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usualcarrot/zh07hfrc/1/

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

subject.skip(1).last().subscribe(function(val) {
  console.log('next:', val);
}, function(val) {
  console.log('error:', val);
}, function() {
  console.log('completed');
});

subject.onNext(1);
subject.onNext(2);
subject.onNext(3);
subject.onNext(4);
subject.onNext(5);
subject.onCompleted();
```

This prints to console:

```
next: 5
completed
```

Instead of `console.log('completed');` you'd put the `resolve(...)`. Maybe this is not even necessary and you can use just return the `Subject` and subscribe to it as well (?) depending on your use case. In that case use [`asObservable()` to hide the fact you're using a `Subject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/asobservable.md). See [similar use-case with `asObservable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703167/changes-in-observable-not-reflected-in-view/39721493#39721493).

Comment: As I understand this will terminate the subject observable. But if I want this to live on?

Comment: I tried to remove all boilerplate from the example. Now that I have it is unclear that this is from an angular2 redux setup. So the source obervable is coming from ng2-redux using the select pattern and looks similar to this: `@select(['foo',]) bar$: Observable<string>;`. So I am not sure if I can ever complete the source observable since that is managed by redux. This is a follow up question to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290225/how-to-use-an-observable-in-angular-2-guards-canactivate

Comment: Well, I'm confused what you actually want to do. You said: *"I want to resolve the promise when the stream completes"* but now you say *"I am not sure if I can ever complete the source observable"* so which one is correct? If you can't complete the Observable then you obviously can't rely on `subscribe()` with "complete" callback and not even on any `last()`, `takeLast()` and similar that work with `completed` signal. So what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I understood, operators return new observables from the source observable. Because I cannot complete the source I thought I could complete the observable returned by `filter` by using  `take/takeLast/...` on it. It works when using `take(1)` as this calls complete. But it is not the latest entry from the stream.

Comment: But if `latestTime$` comes from redux and you have no control over it and you think it never completes then you can't know which value is the "last" one from the stream before it completes. Maybe have a look at [`BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md). You can subscribe it to `latestTime$` and it'll remember the latest value emitted from the source Observable. Then every time you subscribe to the `BehaviorSubject` instance you automatically receive the latest value from `latestTime$`.

Comment: I only need the latest entry in the stream when I call the function. I want it to keep updating and when I click again I want the then latest value. Thanks I will have a look.

Comment: @Markus Were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue with ngrx actions. I also need to get the last action and I am unable to get the latest one.

Comment: @Learning The question is quite old now and I would probably not create the problematic environment this way again. Depending on your setup the answer now would be to avoid promises and subjects within observable streams and then only use operators like `last()` to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I use `combineLatest` for such scenarios. Here is a simple POC:

```js
import { ReplaySubject, combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';

const source = new ReplaySubject();

source.next('1');
source.next('2');
source.next('3');

combineLatest([source, of(true)]).subscribe(([data]) => {
  console.log('data:', data) // data: 3
});
```